# How does jQuery on(close,callback) work? Materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I tried to replicate an issue I encountered at work that I cannot attach multiple materialize drop-downs to the `on close`event.(only the first one is working)

So I make a snippet here.
[materialize multiple dropdown](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/141955/)

Quite the opposite, even though I explicitly select the first drop down using `get[0]` and attach the `close` event, the callback fires when I close the second non-selected drop-down too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like only the first dropdown listens to the event.
if I put

```
$(dropDown).on('close', function() {
    console.log(this)
});
```

`This` always refers to the same obj.
Because of the fact that clicking anywhere other than the dropdown would trigger the event, I thought the second dropdown trigger the close event too.
This weird behavior was because I used a older version of materialize, updated the version and the problem is gone.